# Disable italic in remark environment

Tags: amsthm

When I use `\theoremstyle{definition}` then make a new environment name, when I apply the environment to use, the name itself(for example, notation, claim, ... the name shown at the top of environment) is **bold**. When I use `\theoremstyle{remark}`, it is *italics*. Is there anyway to change the italics to bold?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want it in bold just use the `definition` style instead of the `remark` style. The style names in `amsthm` are probably not well chosen. They should just have been named `headboldbodyitalic` (=plain), `headboldbodynormal` (=definition) `headitalicsbodynormal` (=remark) or something like that. Nobody is forcing you to use the `remark` style for a `remark` env.

Comment: @daleif -- Not meaning to be overly critical, but that choice of names (and style) was set in `amstex`, which was first released in 1981, based on at least 50 years of published work by the American Math Society.  Also, shorter (but distinct and well-documented) names are better for end users.  Granted, it should have been made easier to modify simple elements like the header font; rather than requiring the rather complicated `\newtheoremstyle`.

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton of course this is an exaggeration, my point just is that new users think they should always use the definitions style for definitions or remark style for remarks. Many users does not understand that the remark style has nothing to do with and theorem env one defines named remark.